# Classically, is the notion of a photon superfluous according to special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, absorption

The invariant spacetime interval of a lightlike path is zero.  So a photon is always exchanged between particles that are actually zero interval from each other.  Then, is the concept of the photon strictly necessary, or can we just say one fermion suddenly exchanges energy/momentum with another?

Since the photon is a quantum concept, I'm guessing QFT probably renders this question moot somehow, but I was wondering if there's a classical perspective on it.  But feel free to explain it in quantum terms if that's more relevant.

Comment: Has a photon from the sun ever reached your eye?  Do you consider yourself to be in the same place as the sun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the speed of light is finite, interactions between distant particles can't take place instantaneously. In spite of the spacetime-interval for a lightlike-segment being zero, the temporal and spatial components are generally nonzero.

From a classical point of view, one could refer to light-flash-signals instead of "photons" or "particles of light" when talking about (say) radar measurements and light-clocks... and the Doppler effect with regard to comparing the periods between emissions and the periods between receptions.

However, in processes like the Doppler effect (with regard to frequencies of light) and the Compton effect,
which are associated with energy and momentum and their transfers between other particles, it is convenient to use the "photon" as a lightlike-particle that has energy and momentum (a lightlike 4-momentum).